# what is the difference between population projection and forecast

Tags: hypothesis-testing, forecasting

I don't understand the meaning of the above question so please can you follow up for me please answer it for me today thank

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is specific enough for an answer but it's something.

The concept of a projection is generally used in estimation. If you restrict yourself to the linear case, the projection of $Y$ is the estimate of y that minimizes the residual variance of $Y$ ( it calculates y - yhat and finds the  yhat that minimizes the sum of the distances squared)  by projecting it into the space spanned by columns of $X$. 
( i.e $\hat{\beta} = (X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime Y$).

A forecast can be a projection but it usually refers to a prediction and usually in the time-series framework. So, one might use the projection concept ( i.e: the kalman filter for example uses it ) to forecast but not necessarily because there are many ways that one can forecast $Y$ in time besides projecting it.

Answer (score 1):

When demographers talk about a [population projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_of_population_growth), the "projection" usually just means an estimate that they have projected into the future ---i.e., it is the same as a forecast.  So in the usual context where this term is used, "population projection" is synonymous with "population forecast".  (While [mlofton](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/64098/mlofton) is correct that there is a concept called [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)) in linear algebra, that is not likely to be what people are referring to when talking about a "population projection".)